# Hide button in gridview when field is Null

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, visible, itemtemplate

I have a grid view where some of the rows have attached pictures. when I press Button2 I pull information from the sql record, about which folder on the server that has the pictures.
This works already, but I can not get the button to only be visible in the rows that have image folder attached.

I've googled a long time and found different solutions similar to the following, but I can not get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSodinRSSfeb" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:herning_brand_dk_dbConnectionString %>"                 
    SelectCommand="SELECT PubDateTime, Melding, Station, PhotoFolder FROM OdinRSS ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>    
<asp:GridView ID="GridView14" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSodinRSSfeb" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="500px" OnRowCommand="Button_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PubDateTime" HeaderText="Tidspunkt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Melding" HeaderText="Melding for udkaldet" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Station" HeaderText="Station" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Foto" >
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PhotoFolder") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Foto" Visible='<%# Eval("PhotoFolder") != "Null" %>' 
                            CommandName="ButtonClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PhotoFolder") %>'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My .cs

```
protected void Button_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument != null)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "ButtonClick":
                {
                    int Folder = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    PhotoList(Folder);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

void PhotoList(int FolderNumber)
{
    var imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("PhotoFolder\\" + FolderNumber));
    var imageNames = new string[imagePaths.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        imageNames[i] = imagePaths[i].Substring(imagePaths[i].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    }

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ImageName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(string));

    foreach (var imgName in imageNames)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ImageName"] = RemoveExtension(imgName);
        dr["ImagePath"] = "PhotoFolder/" + FolderNumber + "/" + imgName;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}

string RemoveExtension(string imgName)
{
    return imgName
                .Replace(".jpg", "")
                .Replace(".png", "");
}
```

The sql field "PhotoFolder" is a nvarchar(50). If there is photos for the record, the field has a number from 100 and up, that refares to the folder containing photos. If there are no photo for the record, the field contains "Null"

I have also tried:

```
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Foto" Visible='<%# Eval("PhotoFolder").ToString() != "Null" %>'
```

But the button is shown in all rows, not just the ones that has a string(number) in "PhotoFolder"

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved simple in Inline code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnBranchType1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/" + Eval("branchtype1")+".png" %>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("branchtype1"))=="" ? false : true %>'  Height="20px"/>
```

Here Eval("branchtype1") we are getting value of id from data table like 1, 2, 3 etc. and our image folder consists images like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png etc.,

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("branchtype1"))=="" ? false : true %>'
```

if value doesn't contain any id it will get null. we will compare it with empty string using ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Markup

```
Visible='<%# HideEmptyPhotoFolder(Eval("PhotoFolder")) %>'
```

Code-Behind

```
protected bool HideEmptyPhotoFolder(object photoFolder)
{
    return photoFolder != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(photoFolder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What you describe works fine, but actually it can be shortened even more.
It also works in the following way, without the use of Code-Behind:                     Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PhotoFolder").ToString()) %>'   Thankyou!

Comment: @SørenGinderskov: what if the object Eval returns is null. I just selected one of the ways that works. wanted more readability :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you should write the code for checking the rows containing the image,
you can write the code in RowDatabound event,and set visible property of button to false on that row which doesn't contain image.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that in GridView RowDataBound event.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx